# Installing SSL certificate on a Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nginx-config

I am testing Google Cloud platform to host some WordPress websites and I have deployed a marketplace solution, which is a wordpress optimized install by jetware, packaged with wordpress, Nginx and other stuff. Everything works smoothly, but I cannot enable ssl for my website and install a SSL certificate. I tried some tutorials, but they do not work well with this install. Anyone has some experience on this? Or having some pointers on how to manually install certificates?

Comment: the question is too broad and it does not tell which OS. see [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) and use `certbot`.

Comment: SSL certificates are installed in Apache. Same for every Apache website. If you are having problems, show the steps and the errors. Saying it does not work is not helpful. Show exactly what does not work.

Comment: Sorry if the question is too broad. The problem is that the application is different from a standard installation  documented online. It is a google cloud marketplace app, a wordpress tailored for performance by Jetware. The os is Debian, the web server is Nginx, not Apache. I have installed another Marketplace app. On my first ssh login I was asked to configure a default domain and default ssl certificate. In this case I apparently need to do it manually. I have installed and run certbot but the procedure fails because of some nginx process issue. Web requests are handled by php-fpm process.

Comment: Give us the details of the "some nginx process issue".

Comment: have you found an answer? I am having the same issue with Jetware ngix

Answer (score 0):

If you need SSL certificates on an instance because of services you have running there, install the certificates as described in your application documentation.

Here is documentation to [configure HTTPS with Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) , please share the guides you are following and the errors you found